# How to set the value of a variable to the value of hour selected in date picker

Tags: swift, swift3, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` with the name datePicker. I want to var datePickerHour to be equal to the hour value selected in the date picker. Currently, I am able to get datePicker.date, which comes out as `2017-03-15 05:24:12 +0000`.

The current code is...

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func button(_ sender): Any) {
    let datePickerHour = datePicker.date
    print(datePickerHour)
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
let currentDate = datePicker.date
let calender : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.current as NSCalendar
let datePickerHour = calender.components(NSCalendarUnit.Hour , from: currentDate as Date)
print(datePickerHour)
```

Comment: NSCalendar has been renamed to Calendar

Comment: @paper1111 yes my friend but both are working fine!!

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = datePicker.date

let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour , from: date)
```

It gives an integer which is the hour of the date.

Alternatively you can use the `components(_:​from:​)` method, which returns a `Date` rather than an `Int`